# Google cloud dataproc --files is not working

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I want to copy some property files to master and workers while submitting spark job,
so as stated in the doc I am using --files to copy the files on executors working directory.
but below command is not copying anything in executors working directory. So anybody have idea please share.

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster=cluster-name --class=dataproc.codelab.word_count.WordCount --jars=gs://my.jar --region=us-central1 --files=gs://my.properties -- gs://my/input/ gs://my/output3/
```

Comment: How do you confirm it is not copying the files?

Comment: I checked the working dir, found nothing over there, instead the files are copied in workers at some hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/filecache/ folder and in master at .tmp\job-id\

Comment: The files are only supposed to be copied to executors working directory, which means worker nodes.

Comment: But don't know why it is not copying the files to executors working directory i.e. /hadoop/spark/work/ and option --files, instead it is copying to /hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/filecache/<some_number>/

Comment: @Dagang any idea

Comment: Because executors run in YARN containers, your job can access these files with relative path without knowing the absolute path which is dynamic.

Comment: @Dagang, Actually application-id is generated by the spark in this path. So how that path will be accessible on executors. I mean is there anything available on API to access this path on executors, or how will access it using a relative path

Comment: Can you print the current dir in your job code which runs on executors to see how it relates to the path?

Comment: There should be a place on the YARN logs that shows which files are uploaded, including your jar and that "properties" files. Can you please include that on your question? Thank you!

Comment: Spark will automatically set the working directory of the executors to the temporary directory where the copied files are, have you tried to open the file `my.properties` *without using any path* ? (for instance, `scala.io.Source.fromPath("my.properties")`)

Answer (score 2):

According to [official Spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#important-notes), when Spark is running on Yarn, the Spark executor will use local directory configured for Yarn as working directory, which is by default - `/hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/{userName}/appcache/{applicationId}`.

So based on you description if it dose show up there then it's working as expected.

Comment: Actually this application-id is generated by spark. So how that path will be accessible on executors. I mean is there anything available on API to access this path on executors.

Comment: I am not able to find the file passed using --files option in /hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/{userName}/appcache/{applicationId} folder of worker nodes